# Why the JSON.parse returning [Object Object] instead of value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

here is my json:

```
[
    {
        "customer": "BigCo",
        "performances": [
            {
                "playID": "hamlet",
                "audience": 55
            },
            {
                "playID": "as-like",
                "audience": 35
            },
            {
                "playID": "othello",
                "audience": 40
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

here is my code(environment is node.js):

```
let readFile = require('fs').readFileSync

let invoices = JSON.parse(readFile('./invoices.json', 'utf8'))

console.log(invoices);
```

here is my result:

```
[
  { customer: 'BigCo', performances: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] }
]
```

I have read some questions related, and get some solutions like `invoices = invoices[0]` or `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`.
The thing I really hope to know is the reason.
Why do I get the result `[ [Object], [Object], [Object] ]` and Which part cause the problem?

Comment: NodeJS only shows the contents of objects for two "levels" deeps. Log `console.log(invoices.performances[0])` instead to see the contents of your array. More info can be found here: https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-log-an-object-in-nodejs

Comment: thanks, the answer has completely solved my problem. That is what I looking for

Answer (score -1):

I am no expert but the reason for this is that they are nested objects.

Answer (score -1):

You need to first convert the contents of the file into string and then parse it to JSON.

Use the following code :

```
let readFile = require('fs').readFileSync

let invoices = JSON.parse(readFile('./invoices.json', 'utf8').toString())

console.log(invoices[0]);
```

the output would be :

```
{
  customer: 'BigCo',
  performances: [
    { playID: 'hamlet', audience: 55 },
    { playID: 'as-like', audience: 35 },
    { playID: 'othello', audience: 40 }
  ]
}
```